Which episode of Trailer Park Boys is the "Today, I'm just gonna go and […] ruin everything they're doing" quote from?
Which episode of Trailer Park Boys is this quote from? I tried using Google and even asked ChatGPT, but neither of them could find out.
Here's the quote:

Today, I'm just gonna go and fucking ruin everything they're doing. Fuck them. Teach them a lesson. That I'm in charge, not them.

Video of the quote.
There's another example here:
https://www.facebook.com/100082281931562/videos/449604994721762/

I'm at a loss why this is attracting close votes. ID question are on-topic and this seems perfectly relevant and, hopefully, answerable

Please bear with me as I try to work out how to do that.  It seems to be something that there is no tool for so may need staff assistance.

@BCdotWEB I've now added an ID tag in line with the [meta] discussion: Temporary tags for ID questions while awaiting the unblocking of ID tags

It's not from an episode. It's from a behind-the-scenes skit filmed to go on the DVD for Season 10; titled Sleep Revenge Part 1.



